# jQuery Transparent Countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, countdown

I have seen many countdown's in JS and jQuery so I wanted it to be transparent i.e to match with the Page BG color ? If anyone knows such a countdown please reply and I need it to be in sorta Big FOnts and Vertical ...

Comment: Also, you can probably pick any you want and style it however you wish, such is the beauty of the open web! http://webdesignandseo.net/jquery/clickcount/ - there's a simple click counter

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is pretty good.
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

you can always set the css to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

Modify the css for the background-color and font size.

The class `.hasCountdown` for background-color and `.countdown_amount` for the size of the countdown number.

Comment: you gave the same link as @raklos